# How to Access object created in System.Timers.Timer in a GUI Event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer

I'm using a `System.Timers.Timer` to get a `PrintQueueCollection` every N-seconds so I'm always up to date if something changed. The timer sends a `RefreshEvent` with the PrintQueue so I can handle changes in my Gui.

Here's the Refresh function, the timer calls every n-seconds

```
private void Refresh()
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        try
        {
             // _server == ServerName if isNullOrEmppty it's localhost
            PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer(_server);
            PrintQueueCollection printQueueCollection = printServer.GetPrintQueues();

            foreach (PrintQueue pq in printQueueCollection)
            {
                if (_firstRun) break;

                // List of Unique Printernames so not all printers get 'refreshed'
                if (_printersToMonitor.Contains(pq.Name))
                {
                    var currentPrinter = new Printer(pq);
                    // Event catched in Gui
                    Refreshed?.Invoke(currentPrinter);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The Event is catched in a Control this way

```
// Printer is a Wrapper class that contains the PrintQueue and several other information I need e.g. results of SNMP walks
private void RefreshPrinter(Printer printer)
{
    if (_localPrinters.Count == 0)
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _localPrinters.Add(printer));
    else
    {
        // _localPrinters is a ObservableCollection<Printer> Bound to gui
        foreach (Printer p in _localPrinters.ToList())
        {
            if (p.FullName == printer.FullName)
            {
                p.NumberOfJobs = printer.NumberOfJobs;
                p.Status = printer.Status;
                return;
            }
        }
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _localPrinters.Add(printer));
    }
}
```

So far so good now comes the point I don't know how to handle. The `ObservableCollection<Printer>` is bound to a `DataGrid` were all general information is Displayed. Now if a user double clicks a Row, I want to show some 'deeper' information in a userControl. But I can't find a way to access the `PrintQueue` here because it's the wrong Thread.

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Printer is fine, just the PrintQueue inside is full of System.InvalidOperationException
    Printer p = (sender as DataGridRow)?.DataContext as Printer;
    UcPrinterDetails.InitializeDetails(p.PrintQueue);

    UcPrinterDetails.Visibility = UcPrinterDetails.Visibility != Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

So my question here: What is the best way to access the PrintQueue object and which Thread is the owner of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use object (related to Windows functionality) in different thread then it was created in. 
In the Row_DoubleClick function just call one more time GetPrintQueues method and find the one that you interested in.

Comment: But there must be a way to access  PrintQueue object, i just wanna read properties not even change them.

Comment: So I think the best option in such case is your own object with all properties that you are interested in created in Refresh method and passed to event handler.